# Argument forwarding for no argument cases

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class like this:

```
template<class T> class A : public T {

// this is done to wrap the base class version of a virtual function
virtual void F(int i) {  
  if(i < 0) T::F(-i);
  else T::F(i);
}

//...
```

that needs to be constructible for any set of args the base class can be constructed with:

```
template <typename T1> A(T1 t1) : T(t1) {} 
template <typename T1, typename T2> A(T1 t1, T2 t2) : T(t1, t2) {} 
// ho, hum, copy, paste, yuck.
// ....
```

All's good but for the default constructor:

```
template <> A() : T() {}
```

doesn't compile

```
A() : T() {}
```

fails if T has no default constructor even if A() isn't called.

```
}
```

Is there a way to make `A()` a template without any args?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> fails if T has no default constructor
>   even if A() isn't called.

```
class X
{
public:
    X(int) {}
};

template <class T>
class A: public T
{
public:
    A(): T() {}
    template <class U>
    A(const U& u): T(u) {}
};

int main()
{
    A<X> a(1);
    //A<X> b;
}
```

This appears to compile fine with several compilers. Isn't it the intention of the class templates that unused methods don't cause errors with a particular template parameter, unless actually used?

Perhaps the default constructor for A is being invoked somewhere after all?

---

The standard has this example to illustrate how the class template and member functions are instantiated. Note that the instantiation of the class and the members are separate:

-3- [Example:

```
template<class T> class Z {
public:
    void f();
    void g();
};

void h()
{
    Z<int> a;               //  instantiation of class  Z<int>  required
    Z<char>* p;             //  instantiation of class  Z<char>  not
                //  required
    Z<double>* q;           //  instantiation of class  Z<double>
                //  not required

    a.f();                  //  instantiation of  Z<int>::f()  required
    p->g();                 //  instantiation of class  Z<char>  required, and
                //  instantiation of  Z<char>::g()  required
}
```

Nothing in this example requires class Z, Z::g(), or Z::f() to be implicitly instantiated. ]

This implies, as far as I can see, that not only template methods in a class template are "lazily" instantiated, but so are regular members too.

Comment: Bazaar, I can get your results, now... And that lead to the next question of how do you force the instantiation of methods, but that's a different question.

Answer (score 1):

Might want to give a look at variadic templates if you have access to C++0x to avoid all that boilerplate (below) and scale generically to any number of parameters.

```
template <typename T1> A(T1 t1) : T(t1) {} 
template <typename T1, typename T2> A(T1 t1, T2 t2) : T(t1, t2) {} 
...
```

http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#variadic-templates

Comment: This is what I would have used if I could: http://digitalmars.com/d/2.0/template.html#TemplateTupleParameter C++0x is next on my list. This is what I'm stuck with.

Comment: C++0x has a generic tuple container available in the STL (it's built using variadic templates).

Comment: tuple container? How would that be needed?

Answer (score 0):

If `T` doesn't have a default constructor, then you don't really have any options. `A() : T() { }` is an obvious error in this case. Give a broader view of the situation you're in, maybe there's a better way / less convoluted way of doing this entirely.

Comment: Yes it would be an error. However it wouldn't be if I could some how force that constructor to be a template. That would work because template are lazy; they don't do semantic checking unless you call them, so even though `T()` would fail, it isn't an error as long as I don't call `A<T>()`.

Comment: yea I see what you mean; what about `template<int throwaway = 0> A() : T() { }`

Comment: to quote clang: `a template parameter of a function template cannot have a default argument in C++98`

Answer (score 0):

To sum up, you can't compile `T()` if `T` does not have default constructor.